# Django multiple lookup **kwargs

Tags: python, django

I have the below function in django which works well, when just looking up based on a single lookup parameter (unique_id). However, I'm trying to get it work with multiple lookup parameters (for e.g. a table with a unique_together constraint which needs both fields in order to retrieve a unique result).

The previously working function is:

```
def create_or_update_if_diff(unique_id, defaults, model):
    """Helper function which is similar to update_or_create(), but will compare defaults to database entry
     and only update when there is any difference"""
    try:
        instance = model.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        instance = model.objects.create(unique_id=unique_id, **defaults)
        sys.stdout.write('New {} created: {}\n'.format(instance.__class__.__name__, instance.unique_id))
        return instance
    else:
        for key, value in defaults.items():
            attr = getattr(instance, key)
            if attr != value:
                # If any change detected update all for efficiency
                model.objects.filter(unique_id=unique_id).update(**defaults)
                instance.refresh_from_db()
                sys.stdout.write('{}: {} updated \n'.format(instance.__class__.__name__, instance.unique_id))
                return instance
        return instance
```

Called with e.g.

```
prices = create_or_update_if_diff(unique_id=till_detail['Id'], defaults=defaults,
                                             model=Price)
```

The amended function is:

```
def create_or_update_if_diff(model, defaults=None, **lookup):
    """Helper function which is similar to update_or_create(), but will compare defaults to database entry
     and only update when there is any difference"""
    defaults = defaults or {}
    try:
        instance = model.objects.get(**lookup)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        instance = model.objects.create(**lookup, **defaults)
        sys.stdout.write('New {} created: {}\n'.format(instance.__class__.__name__, instance.unique_id))
        return instance
    else:
        for key, value in defaults.items():
            attr = getattr(instance, key)
            if attr != value:
                # If any change detected update all for efficiency
                model.objects.filter(**lookup).update(**defaults)
                instance.refresh_from_db()
                sys.stdout.write('{}: {} updated \n'.format(instance.__class__.__name__, instance.unique_id))
                return instance
        return instance
```

Which I tried to call with e.g.

```
lookup = {'name': default_product_string, 'supplier': supplier}
    default_product_instance = create_or_update_if_diff(lookup=lookup, defaults={'payment_method': payment_method_instance},
                                                           model=Product)
```

However I get the below error presumably because I have structured the function incorrently:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'lookup' into field.`

Comment: In your call you name the (implied) dictionary but the function signature expects keyword arguments after the defaults and model args. Either name the lookup dictionary or pass in the dict after the named arguments.

Comment: Thanks - still thinking through the logic of how that works, but it seems to make sense (I removed the ** from lookup in the function definition).  However I now get an error of `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot update model field <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: payment_method> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).` when called as per the 2nd example

Comment: Yeah, you have to do some introspection of the objects you're working with in this more generic method - you might have to dive into the model meta API to get this method working. If you need this for something mission critical, go for it - otherwise I would stick with django methods to handle the model dirty work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a mistake in sending `kwargs`, this is how it works...

Lets create one sample `lookup` dict..

```
>>> lookup = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Simulating `create_or_update_if_diff` method...

```
>>> def create_or_update_if_diff(model, defaults=None, **lookup):
...     print lookup
```

If you assign `lookup=lookup` while calling the method....this mean you are creating one `key word argument` called `lookup`, ideally you are sending only one key word argument

```
>>> create_or_update_if_diff('model', lookup=lookup)
{'lookup': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

> > > Since you model doesn't have the `lookup` field, you are getting `FieldError` exception.

If you pass `lookup` dict like below...you are sending two key word arguments `a and b` to the method..

```
>>> create_or_update_if_diff('model', **lookup)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

So, the logic here is your `lookup` dict `{'a':1, 'b':2}` having two keys `a and b` will be treated like below..

```
>>> create_or_update_if_diff('model', a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Hope this helps you to understand how `**kwargs` works...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that's a great help.  I'm not clear on how to deal with the `instance.unique_id` part of the function now I'm using **lookup, `getattr(instance, **lookup)` doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @Yunti `getattr` can only check for one `attribute` at a time and that too argument must be a`string`, so `getattr(instance, **lookup)` this part is not a good idea....Also, if you like the answer you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `lookup=lookup` as parameter, you would get `{'lookup': {<your original dict>}}` in the function. I think you should just do in your function `create_or_update_if_diff`:

```
lookup_params = lookup['lookup']
instance = model.objects.get(lookup_params)
```

Comment: Don't think that works as I fairly sure you can't have a positional argument after a keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `lookup` correctly, here is how it suppose to be:

```
lookup = {'name': default_product_string, 'supplier': supplier}
defaults = {'payment_method': payment_method_instance}
create_or_update_if_diff(defaults=defaults, model=Product, **lookup)
```